# I am using dataset CIC-MalDroid-2020 with 50,621 columns csv file. To analyze I want to import it to wamp SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, import

I am using CIC-MalDroid-2020 dataset with 50621 columns and want to import it into SQL Server. I tried to import it using server by default method. I have increased memory limit, upload size, execution time etc. I even enabled partial import feature but even after 5 hours of uploading not a single row has been imported.

I don't know what to do

I was trying this solution here
https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/

but in this solution table is supposed to be created manually and its impossible to write 50621 column names.

Please let me know about any software or any other solution if available.

Comment: If you have a dataset with 50K+ columns then you're going to need to very likely normalise that dataset in your ETL process before you import it into SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems,SQL SERVER is not for this task
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Columns per table   1,024   Tables that include sparse column sets include up to 30,000 columns.

Comment: So that means I can't import this dataset into sql serever.

Comment: @SafiaMansoor As a single table - yes. If you want to divide / group the columns then you must use separate related tables. It is unusual to even encounter the column-per-table limit - perhaps you should consider a very different schema as already suggested.